# Nuxt 3 routing taking some time to change page on very first time

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs3

I am working on Nuxt 3 project with **SSR: FALSE** and set the menu with the default Nuxt 3 as per the folder structure standard. My issue is when we come to the website then initially if we change one page to another page after clicking on the menu then it takes a bit time and then it rendered the page.

If we do the same thing the second time then it all works fine and loads the page without any page. Maybe there are some chunk cache issues?

I have written the main API code to a page and divided the HTML code into small components but the still issue happens the very first time.

**API Composable**

```js
export const useGet = async (url, params, fetchType = "useFetch") => {
  url = runtimeConfig.public.apiBase + url;
  let parameters = {
    headers: prepareHeader(),
  };
  if (params) {
    parameters["params"] = params;
  }
  return await useFetch(url, parameters);
};
```

**Pages/user-details.vue**

```html
<template>
  <el-tabs
    v-model="activeTabName"
    @tab-click="handleClick"
  >
    <el-tab-pane :label="Tabs.personalDetails.title" name="personal-details">
      <LazyPersonaldetailsPersonalDetailsTab
        v-if="activeTabName == 'personal-details'"
        :form-data="formData"
        :loader="loader"
        @on-submit="submitForm"
      />
    </el-tab-pane>
    <el-tab-pane :label="Tabs.addressDetails.title" name="address">
      <LazyPersonaldetailsAddressTab
        v-if="activeTabName == 'address'"
        :form-data="formData.addressDetails"
        :loader="loader"
        @submit-form="submitForm"
      />
    </el-tab-pane>
    <el-tab-pane :label="Tabs.currentEmploymentDetails.title" 
      name="employment-details">
      <LazyPersonaldetailsEmploymentDetailsTab
        v-if="activeTabName == 'employment-details'"
        :form-data="formData"
        :loader="loader"
        @on-submit="submitForm"
      />
    </el-tab-pane>
    <el-tab-pane :label="Tabs.incomeDetails.title" name="income-details">
      <LazyPersonaldetailsIncomeDetailsTab
        v-if="activeTabName == 'income-details'"
        :form-data="formData"
        :loader="loader"
        @on-submit="submitForm"
      />
    </el-tab-pane>
  </el-tabs>
</template>

<script setup>
import { PERSONAL_DETAILS_TABS as Tabs } from "@/constants/app";
definePageMeta({
  middleware: ["auth"],
});
useHead({
  title: setPageTitle("Personal Details"),
});
const route = useRoute();
//Form data object
const formData = reactive({
  personalDetails: {
    prefix: "Mr",
    ...
    ...
  },
  contactDetails: {
    email: "",
    phoneNumber: "",
  },
  addressDetails: [
    {
      address: "",
      street: "",
      ...
      ...
    },
  ],
  currentEmploymentDetails: {
    employmentType: "",
    ...
    ...
  },
  employerAddress: {
    address: "",
    ...
    ...
  },
  previousEmploymentDetails: [
    {
      occupation: "",
      ...
    },
  ],
  incomeDetails: [
    {
      amount: "",
      ...
    },
  ],
  additionalIncome: false,
});
const activeTabName = ref("personal-details");

//Get personal details
const getDetails = async () => {
  const { data, error } = await useGet(
    "user/get/" + userInfo.userId
  );
  if (error.value) {
    loader.card = false;
    return useErrorHandling(error.value);
  }
  if (data.value) {
    let response = data.value.data;
    if ("personalDetails" in response) {
      formData.personalDetails = response.personalDetails.personalDetails;
      formData.contactDetails = response.personalDetails.contactDetails;
      if ("spouseDetails" in response.personalDetails.personalDetails) {
        formData.personalDetails.spouseDetails = response.personalDetails.personalDetails.spouseDetails;
      } else {
        formData.personalDetails.spouseDetails = {
          prefix: "",
          firstName: "",
          middleName: "",
          lastName: "",
          gender: "",
          citizenStatus: "",
        };
      }
    }
    if ("addressDetails" in response && response.addressDetails.length) {
      formData.addressDetails = response.addressDetails;
    }
    if ("employmentDetails" in response) {
      if ("previousEmploymentDetails" in response.employmentDetails && 
        response.employmentDetails.previousEmploymentDetails.length) {
        formData.previousEmploymentDetails =
          response.employmentDetails.previousEmploymentDetails;
      }
      formData.currentEmploymentDetails = response.employmentDetails.currentEmploymentDetails;
      formData.employerAddress = response.employmentDetails.employerAddress;
    }
    if ("incomeDetails" in response && response.incomeDetails.length > 0) {
      formData.incomeDetails = response.incomeDetails;
      formData.incomeDetails[0]["additionalIncome"] = false;
    }
    loader.card = false;
  }
};

onMounted(() => {
  getDetails();
});
</script>
```

This is the my structure of code I mentioned above and I am using the `useFetch` to get data from API.

I have shared only one page code but another page structure is similar

Please help or suggest to me if I'm going in the wrong direction. Also, let me know if need more details.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you load anything from an external API? Are you using "useAsyncData()" if so? What's happening from code side exactly on your end?

Comment: @MarkusG. Thanks for your revert!
I have edited the questions and added my one page code so you can get an idea about my structure. I have used the `useFetch` composable to fetch data as you can check on my top code. What I did is I just created a common API composable and each function I have used nuxt 3 default API composable for different `POST, PUT, GET` methods. Please let me know still you required more info.

Comment: @MarkusG. Can you please share your thought on the same?

Comment: Try to log/debug all steps and inspect the network tab what's taking that amount of time which prevents rendering your page. If the API is slow and you use an await() it stops rendering and waits for the response.